# How to set jsonarray to textview?

Tags: android

I am getting a json array from webservice , but when i set the value to the textview i am getting only the last value.

**Code** :

```
JSONObject openhrsjson = new JSONObject(opening_hours);
String resultOpnHrs = openhrsjson.getString(WEEKDAY_TEXT);                              
JSONArray jsonArrayOpnHrs = new JSONArray(resultOpnHrs);
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayOpnHrs.length();j++){
    final String openhrs = jsonArrayOpnHrs.getString(j);
    Log.i("openhrs",openhrs);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtOpenHrs.setText(openhrs);
        }
     });
    }
```

**Logcat** :

```
I/resultOpnHrs﹕ ["Monday: Open 24 hours","Tuesday: Open 24 hours","Wednesday: Open 24 hours","Thursday: Open 24 hours","Friday: Open 24 hours","Saturday: Open 24 hours","Sunday: Open 24 hours"]
```

> I/openhrs﹕ Monday: Open 24 hours I/openhrs﹕ Tuesday: Open 24 hours
>   I/openhrs﹕ Wednesday: Open 24 hours I/openhrs﹕ Thursday: Open 24 hours
>   I/openhrs﹕ Friday: Open 24 hours I/openhrs﹕ Saturday: Open 24 hours
>   I/openhrs﹕ Sunday: Open 24 hours

How to set the whole string value to the textview ?

Thanks

Comment: String s = jsonArray.toString();

Comment: @RakshitNawani i am getting the result with square brackets , inverted commas and commas in the textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your string openhrs to openhrs += jsonarrayopenhrs.getstring(j)

it will add every value of json array to the string openhrs.

what youre doing is youre replacing the value of openhrs each time the loop gets in your code thats why you always get the last result

Answer (score 0):

You should append all your string in one String data type than set to **editText**    Something like this :

```
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
result.append( a[i] );
}
String mynewstring = result.toString();
```

Now set you mynewString to the EditText!!

Answer (score 0):

May be you are searching for appending the texts like here,

```
txtOpenHrs.setText("");

JSONObject openhrsjson = new JSONObject(opening_hours);
String resultOpnHrs = openhrsjson.getString(WEEKDAY_TEXT);                              
JSONArray jsonArrayOpnHrs = new JSONArray(resultOpnHrs);
for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayOpnHrs.length();j++){
    final String openhrs = jsonArrayOpnHrs.getString(j);
    Log.i("openhrs",openhrs);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            txtOpenHrs.append(openhrs); //Append texts to textView

        }
     });
    }
```

Comment: i was doing this previously , but i am getting same result , but if i do jsonArrayOpnHrs.toString then i am getting all values but with [ ] and inverted commas

Comment: yeah thats what happens.